# Docker postgresql container IP address changes whenever it restarts

Tags: python, docker

```sh
$ docker run -d \
    --name some-postgres \
    -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres \
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword \
    -p 5432:5432 \
    postgres
```

I build postgresql container like above. Then when try to access Postgresql server. I always set the IP address like this in Python with Flask-SQLAlchemy:

```py
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = postgresql://postgres:securepass@host.docker.internal:5432/some_db_name'
```

instead of writing "host.docker.internal" can I set the IP address as static one?

Comment: I don't understand your problem here.  Why not use `postgresql://postgres:securepass@localhost:5432/some_db_name`, which should work both inside and outside your container given that you've mapped the internal port number to the same external port number.  If you're talking about accessing your postgres container from another container, there are standard ways of doing that with Docker's DNS support.  You shouldn't ever need to specify an IP, and I'd suggest that you try hard to avoid needing a special setup for your container(s) given that what you're doing seems very simple and standard.

Comment: Localhost inside the container and localhost outside the container resolve differently, therefore it should not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom network:

```
docker network create --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 customnet
```

then, run the container

```
docker run -d \
--name some-postgres \
-e POSTGRES_USER=postgres \
-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword \
-p 5432:5432 \
--net customnet
--ip 172.18.0.33
postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also choose the IP addresses for the container with --ip and --ip6 flags when you start the container on a user-defined network. See [Connect a container to a network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#connect-a-container-to-a-network---network)

Example:

```
$ docker run -itd --network=my-net --ip=10.10.9.75 busybox
```

If you never created a docker network, also check out [docker network create](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/).